# Sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: session in prepared state

Tags: sqlalchemy

**Sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: session in prepared state**

I have built a social media like webapp which through infinite scrolling uploads more posts as you scroll.
Though if I like a post as I am scrolling I get errors while in development mode.

I am using python/flask for backend.

If I scrolling my feed and simultaneously liking a post I get, in development mode, the errror

```
"sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'prepared' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction."
```

This has so far only happened in development mode and not in production mode but I am afraid that it will be a problem if more people start to use it.

Is this an error that will only be a problem in development or will this come up in production as well if I get a significant amount of users?

I have tried incorporating try except statements in my backend code which takes care of the error but it leads to other error so I would like to know if this is a problem that will be a larger issue later on or if it is only a problem in development?

Thanks

---

I tried adding a reproducible example but it was quite difficult

**Beginning with the infinite scrolling.**
In this case I began by loading the indexes of the different posts

*Front end*

HTML

```
 <div   class="flow">
   <div class="flowpost" v-for="post in postlists" :key="post.id" >
     <PostTemplate :iterated_list ="post.id"  ></PostTemplate>
   </div>
 </div>
```

where postlists contains the id of the different posts

Script

```
  mounted(){
      window.onscroll = () => {
    let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    if (bottomOfWindow) {
      this.addmore()
    }
  };
  }
```

The method addmore calls the get_index_list_of_posts function to load more posts

**Backend**

```
def get_index_of_list_of_posts():
    user_id = request.args.get("userid")
    group_action_id = request.args.get("group_action_id")
    page_nr = request.args.get("page_nr")
    total_pages = 0
    result_dict = {}

other_posts_query__ = Session.query(mvpUsersToPosts.id).filter(mvpPosts.id==mvpUsersToPosts.mvp_posts_id  ).order_by(mvpPosts.datetime.desc()) 

pagettt = Paginator(other_posts_query__, 4)

p = pagettt.page(page_nr)
post_query = p.object_list
result_post = []
postlist = []

for post  in post_query:
    result_post = {
        "message":message,
        "id": post[0]
    }

    postlist.append(result_post)


result_dict_list = {}


result_dict_list["posts"] = postlist
result_dict_list["current_page_nr"] = page_nr
result_dict_list["total_page_nr"] = total_pages


posts_result = json.dumps(result_dict_list)
return posts_result
```

I then fill the posts with its data by calling the following backend function from the PostTemplate component.

```
def get_postlista_to_posttemplate():    
userid = request.args.get("userid")
postid = request.args.get("postid")
    result_post = []
    postlist = []

post_query = Session.query( mvpPosts,mvpUsers, mvpUsersToPosts,mvpSolutionTags).filter(mvpUsersToPosts.userid == mvpUsers.id ,mvpUsersToPosts.mvp_posts_id == mvpPosts.id, mvpUsersToPosts.id ==postid,   mvpPosts.id==mvpPostsToSolutionTags.mvp_posts_id, mvpSolutionTags.id==mvpPostsToSolutionTags.tagid).all()

    get_total_liked_query = Session.query( func.sum(mvpliked.liked)).filter(mvpliked.postid == postid).all()


    for post, users,user2post, tag  in post_query:

        result_post = {
            "postid": user2post.id,
            "mvp_post_postid" : post.id,
            "posttitle":post.posttitle,
            "posttype":post.posttype,
            "postimage":post.postimagevideo,
            'postliked':is_liked,
            }

        postlist.append(result_post)

    posts_result = json.dumps(postlist)

return posts_result
```

The prepared state error occurs by the get_total_liked_query which I then wrapped in a try/except statement which did not help.

I can then like a post which is done with the following backend function.

```
  def like_post():
    reply = request.get_json()
    post_id = reply["post_id"]
    user_id= reply["user_id"]

    
    like_query = Session.query(mvpliked.liked).filter(mvpliked.postid == post_id, mvpliked.userid == user_id ).distinct(mvpliked.postid).all()

    if len(like_query) ==0:
        newrow = mvpliked(postid = post_id, userid = user_id, liked=1)
        Session.add(newrow)
        Session.commit()

    else:

        if (like_query[0][0] == 1):
            like_value = 0
        else:
            like_value = 1

        Session.query(mvpliked.liked).filter(mvpliked.postid == post_id, mvpliked.userid == user_id ).update({mvpliked.liked: like_value })
        Session.commit()

    return ""
```

The invalidrequest error seem to occur when functions like_post() and get_postlista_to_posttemplate() run simultaneously.

---

Session code

```
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL_prod)
Base = declarative_base(engine)


def  loadDatabaseSession():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    DatabaseSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    DatabaseSession = DatabaseSession()
    return DatabaseSession

Session = loadDatabaseSession()
```

Comment: Updated now, it is quite hard to create a small reproducible example since there are a lot of components involved but hopefully it clears the problem up a little. Thanks

Comment: Do you create a new `Session` for each request?

Comment: Good question, I am not sure. I believe it is taken care of by the Sessionmaker. 

From what I understand I only create a new session when I commit but I can be wrong


I have been using the following link:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html

Comment: If `loadDatabaseSession` is only called once then the problem may be that you are always using the same session (you can check by printing the session).  If that's the case [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html#unitofwork-contextual) may be helpful.

Comment: Yes it all seems to be the same session. I will check the link to try and fix it. Thanks for the help : )